# Silent login using Username in Azure Active Directory in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, azure-active-directory

I am developing app using Xamarin Forms. I have created a directory on azure portal. As i see references over internet , active directory authentication uses Microsofts login page to log in.

I want to create native login form and pass user name to active directory and authenticate it.

Is it possible to pass user credentials programatically and authenticate user?
How can i pass user credentials?

I have tried following but i got "(411) Length required" exception

```
            var request = WebRequest.Create(string.Format(@"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/oauth2/token?client_id=5e811f4f-4fa4-451e-a439-ca05cabc02d7&grant_type=password&username=02atul.com@gmail.com&password=userpassword&scope=openid", tenant));
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.Method = "POST";
            using (HttpWebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync() as HttpWebResponse)
            {
                if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    Debug.WriteLine("Error fetching data. Server returned status code: {0}", response.StatusCode);
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    var content = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(content))
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("Response contained empty body...");
                    }
                    else {
                        Debug.WriteLine("Response Body: \r\n {0}", content);
                    }
                }
            }
```

My username is my email id. Is it correct user name? As i am getting bad request error now. What's missing?

[image: AAD User Name]

Comment: Most OAuth2-based authentication (now) require/enforce that you use their OAuth login process to obtain that golden access and refresh token. Microsoft, Google, Facebook, (etc.) OAuth2 systems are all based upon that security fact now. The huge upside is if a user logins via your website and your app is using Android Chrome `CustomTabs` or iOS `SFSafariViewController` for the OAuth UI/process, then your user does not have to login again and Vice Versa.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But i want to authenticate active directory silently by any way. Is this possible in any way? Just want to pass user email and password.

Comment: Technically it is possible of course if you handle that complete OAuth2 client process yourself as you need to obtain the access token to be able to do anything with the Graph/AD Rest-based API, but I highly recommend you do not go down that path... Review the MS docs for `Protocol Flow` vs. `Authentication flow`, it also means that you have falsely register your "app" as a daemon/server : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-scenarios

Answer (score 3):

Technically you could use username and password flow which is described in more detail [here with ADAL](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/07/08/using-adal-net-to-authenticate-users-via-usernamepassword/).

However, you need to revisit your scenario and understand if it really accomplishes what the Azure Active Directory Platform is for.

Users use OAuth2 based authentication to get the security and safety of only having to share their passwords with trusted identity providers like MS, FB, Google, etc... In general, the safety conscious person will NOT want to type in a password into your random website, and trust that you do not abuse that information. If you want to use AAD, you should also use our login experiences, as this is really what the customer is paying for in our service in many regards.

EDIT: If ADAL no longer supports this flow, you can simply generate the http requests yourself:

```
POST: https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxx.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/token

Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
resource={resource}&client_id={clientId}&grant_type=password&username={userName}&password={password}&scope=openid&client_secret={clientSecret}
```

Comment: I've already gone through given link. AquireToken method doesn't accept user credentials now. Its old post.

Comment: I have updated my answer to include the raw HTTP POST request that would accomplish the same behavior. Note specifically here that `grant_type = password`, which is what enabled this all to work.

Comment: @Shwan thanks for reference. Can you help me a bit? I am getting "The remote server returned an error: (411) Length Required" exception from remote server.

Comment: Did you pass a content-type?

Comment: Yes, i've added as you mentioned in your answer.

Comment: I've added code in my question @Shawn. Also please help me out if i want to sign up user using same method. Or refer me documentation if any available for azure active directory.

Comment: I noticed that your sign in email is a "gmail" account. What kind of user account are you signing in with here? Remember, this process only works for AAD accounts.

Comment: I have added screenshot of my user name. I have solved issue of length required. But now i am getting Bad Request error.

Comment: Can you share the contents of the Error Body? There must be additional details as to help you with the bad request error. Can you also share your solution for the Length error so that you can help others with a similar problem?

Comment: Sure! Let me share stuffs. Can i have your email id so i can send error body and solution, if you don't mind? Or send me test mail to 02atul.com@gmail.com. And Thanks for your attention on this.